# access speed to static and heap memory

Tags: c++, memory, static, heap-memory

There are a lot of topics about access speed to stack and heap variables, but I couldn't find question and proper answer about access speed for static and heap variables.

What should I prefer (in terms of access speed) if object lifetime is the same as program lifetime? Which is faster - using statically-allocated object or object in a heap?

I'm talking about C++, if relevant.

Comment: With most modern operating systems, no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Absolutely. Once your program is loaded, CPU simply does not know what sort of memory (heap or static) it is dealing with.

The above statement is true for 98% of most common CPU architectures/implementations. Although some computers may have different areas of memory that work with different speeds. If this is the case you need to check this. How this special memory is mapped - this depends on a particular platform/configuration.

Depending on the compiler/environment programs with big static areas may load somewhat slower. But this is not an absolute rule.

It would be better to think about locality of your data (is your pieces of data stay close to each other or not) and how one value will kick out other value out of the CPU cache. Loading something to cache is 10-100 times slower than accessing something that is already in the cache. This will make VERY noticeable difference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, data locality and program architecture is out of scope of the question. I just couldn't find good info about actual access time for static/heap memory and asked community about it.